# How to use special characters in template variables in jinja2?

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

I have a requirement where I want to render values containing `"."`,  `".."`,  `"/"` and `"//"` in jinja2.

For example I have a dictionary :

```
values= {'pre_package_information[1]/comment': 'Device: 14.2', 'post_package_information[1]/comment': 'Device: 14.2-2'}
```

Now I am rendering this value using jinja:

```
mssg= "Test Succeeded!! Checking Device version for 14.2 release {{pre_package_information[1]/comment}}"
jinja2.Template(mssg).render(values)
```

But it is giving error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'pre_package_information' is undefined
```

Looks like it is not taking `"["` and `"/"` in templates. How to pass these special characters. I faced problems with other characters also like `"."` and `".."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you access the variable in the template needs to be like this

`{{ values['pre_package_information[1]/comment'] }}`

and call the render like `render(values=values)`

Just like in python you cannot have variables with special characters

Answer (score 4):

Jinja requires that all top-level names are valid Python identifiers; see the [*Notes on identifiers* section](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#identifier-naming):

> Jinja2 uses the regular Python 2.x naming rules. Valid identifiers have to match `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`.

Either provide identifiers that match that requirement, or wrap your dictionary in another to indirectly look up your keys in that:

```
values = {'pre_package_information[1]/comment': 'Device: 14.2',  'post_package_information[1]/comment': 'Device: 14.2-2'}
mssg= ("Test Succeeded!! Checking Device version for 14.2 release "
       "{{values['pre_package_information[1]/comment']}}")
jinja2.Template(mssg).render(values=values)
```

Note that here the `values` dictionary is passed in as a keyword argument, so it'll be accessible as `values` in the template.

Demo:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> values = {'pre_package_information[1]/comment': 'Device: 14.2',  'post_package_information[1]/comment': 'Device: 14.2-2'}
>>> mssg= ("Test Succeeded!! Checking Device version for 14.2 release "
...        "{{values['pre_package_information[1]/comment']}}")
>>> jinja2.Template(mssg).render(values=values)
u'Test Succeeded!! Checking Device version for 14.2 release Device: 14.2'
```